# How can I create an account in mint.com for cash that I keep in my home and not in a bank account?

Tags: mint.com

I keep some cash stowed away in my mattress for rainy days and/or emergencies and would like to track it with Mint just as I do my checking or savings account. I realize this account could not be linked to anything that would automatically import my transactions, but that's OK - there won't be many transactions so manually inputting them will work fine.

When I try to add a cash account in Mint, it seems to insist on linking it somewhere. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was posted in response to the same question on the Mint.com community forums:

> jamesyelverton24  1 day ago Unfortunately, Mint does not include a
>   method to effectively handle cash transactions from cash holdings ...
>   for regular expenses or for emergency use.
>
> Cash you are holding can certainly be added as an asset but your can't
>   enter transactions.  The Mint way is to withdraw ATM cash and then
>   mark cash expenses to be debited from the ATM withdrawal.  From
>   discussions in Community, this apparently does not work properly.

https://mint.lc.intuit.com/questions/1012983-how-can-i-create-an-account-for-cash-that-i-keep-in-my-home-and-not-in-a-bank-account?jump_to=answer_2269729